# Simplify $\sqrt{x(x^{2n+1})} \over \sqrt[3]{x^{3n}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I need to simplify 
$$\sqrt{x(x^{2n+1})} \over \sqrt[3]{x^{3n}}$$

I think I can do it, if I knew how to do:

$$x(x^{2n+1})$$

wouldn't it be

$$x^{2n +2}$$

Comment: You are right in saying $x(x^{2n+1}) = x^{2n+2}$. This follows the general formula that $x^ax^b = x^{a+b}$.

Comment: Good so far. One then has to be careful in finding $\sqrt{x^{2n+2}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt{x(x^{2n+1})}}{\sqrt[3]{x^{3n}}}=\frac{\left(x^{2n+2}\right)^{1/2}}{x^{3n/3}}=\frac{x^{\frac{2n+2}2}}{x^n}=\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^n}=...$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would be right. This whole problem stems from your understanding of two basic principles of bases and exponents:

- $x^a*x^b = x^{a+b}$
- $\frac{x^a}{x^b} = x^{a-b}$

Does that help?